# display binary image with php, jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this code which makes a binary image from a normal image and displays it into an .img

```
 $host=$_POST['hostname'];
  $type=$_POST['type_char'];
 include('rrdtools.inc.php');
  include('graphs/'.$type.'.inc.php');


  function graph_error($string,$rrd_options)
  {


  $graphfile ='/tmp/'. strgen().'.png';

  $rrd_options .= ' HRULE:0#555555';
   $rrd_options .= " --title='".$string."'";

   rrdtool_graph($graphfile, $rrd_options);

   header('Content-type: image/png');
   $fd = fopen($graphfile, 'r');
    fpassthru($fd);
   fclose($fd);
   unlink($graphfile);

    }


     graph_error($type,$rrd_options);
```

I send the hostname,type_char to the file using ajax and this is the code

```
$('.print_graph').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var type_char='fortigate_sessions';//$('#graph').val();
    var hostname='10.10.0.144';//$(this).attr('id');
    //$('#device_host').val(id);

    $.ajax({  
type: 'POST',  
url: 'SNMP/graph.php', 
data: {'hostname':hostname,'type_char':type_char },
success: function(data) {
     alert(data);
        // show the response
   $("#grph").attr("src", 'SNMP/graph.php');
         console.log(data);
}
});
```

as you can see in the javascript code I used this code to display image

```
$("#grph").attr("src", 'SNMP/graph.php');
```

and this code will call graph.php again without parameters and the result is wrong 
how can I pass parameters to graphs.php . 
I wish I explained my problem clearly

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: the error is graph.php need to pass tow variable (hostname, type_char ) but when I pass this variables using jquery the image is generated successfully  but after that the code into success function                      
         $("#grph").attr("src", 'SNMP/graph.php'); will run and regenerate another image which will be wrong image because it not passed variables when called ('SNMP/graph.php') file

Comment: Instead of using ajax to POST the parameters, append them to the URL that the `img` div loads as a query string. Modify the PHP to use  `_GET` instead of `_POST`.

Comment: "a binary image from a normal image"...all image files on a computer consist of binary data. Not really sure what you mean by this phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by making graph.php look for GET parameters instead of POST and then setting the image source directly without using AJAX:

Change

```
$host=$_POST['hostname'];
$type=$_POST['type_char'];
```

to

```
$host=$_GET['hostname'];
$type=$_Get['type_char'];
```

and also change

```
$.ajax({  
  type: 'POST',  
  url: 'SNMP/graph.php', 
  data: {'hostname':hostname,'type_char':type_char },
  success: function(data) {
     alert(data);
    // show the response
    $("#grph").attr("src", 'SNMP/graph.php');
   console.log(data);
  }
});
```

to simply

```
$("#grph").attr("src", 'SNMP/graph.php?hostname='+hostname+'&type_char='+type_char);
```

This will mean that the image data returned by graph.php is used directly in the `img` tag instead of ending up in a JavaScript variable.

---

P.S. I note you are using the `$type` variable to directly create an `include()` statement in PHP. This is potentially very insecure, as you're letting the client have very direct control over what code is executed and this could be abused to execute code which shouldn't be executed at this time. You should make sure the value submitted contains a value you are expecting and is allowed before using it in your include() statement.